# Proving $\nabla(f,(xy))$ is a linear isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2,(x,y)\to(x^2-y^2,2xy)$. Prove that $f$ is not injective but $f$ is a local difeomorphism in all the points of $\mathbb{R}^2$

I decided to use the Inverse function theorem, stated:

> **Theorem**: Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a function of $\mathscr{C}^r(r\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\})$. Consider $a\in\Omega$ such as $f´(a):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear isomorphism and $b=f(a)$. Therefore there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $\Omega$ and there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(U)=V$ and $f:U\to V$ is a difeomorphism of $\mathscr{C}^r$ class.

My strategy is to prove that $\nabla(f,(x,y))$ is a linear isomorphism such that I can apply the Inverse function theorem to conclude that $f$ is an open map and a difeomorphism.

I computed the gradient:

$\nabla(f,(xy))=\begin{bmatrix}2x&-2y\\2y&2x\end{bmatrix}$

$\det\nabla(f,(xy))=4x^2+4y^2>0$

I know what is a isomorphism from linear algebra(a bijective linear function between two vector spaces).

**Question:**

On this case I am not seeing how to prove $\nabla(f,(xy))$ is a linear isomorphism. How can I do it? Can someone provide me a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should start by taking partial derivatives correctly. Also, do you really write $f'(a)$ as the gradient when you have a map $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin            Done it! The problem is that $f´(a)$ was not adopted by me but by the author from where I copied the inverse function theorem statement. As you can notice I have adopted $\nabla$.

Comment: Yeah, well, it's customary to use $\nabla$ only for scalar-valued functions (or, in advanced differential geometry, for a covariant derivative operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$ is indeed not injective, and hence not a global diffeomorphism.

Consider the points $(x,y)=(-1,1), (-1,1)$. Both points map to $(0,-2)$ in the range. We can actually classify all points where injectivity fails.

In order to have a diffeomorphism, we start by considering the Jacobian $\nabla(f)=\begin{bmatrix}2x&-2y\\2y&2x\end{bmatrix}$. Note, the Jacobian is invertible when $det(\nabla(f))\neq 0$, so when $4x^2-4y^2\neq 0$, Which reduces to $x^2=y^2$.

According to the Inverse Function Theorem, the map $f$ is a diffeomorphism on the set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2\neq y^2$}.

Note that the map $f$ is a diffeomorphism on $S$ since when $f$ is restricted to $S$, we have an injective map.

**EDIT**

To show surjectivity, consider that we consider the map $(x^2-y^2,2xy)=(a,b)$ and we want this to be well-defined $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. We can "solve component-wise". We can set $x^2-y^2=a$, and note for any $a$, for any $x$ (WLOG), we have $x^2=y^2-a$ and $x=\sqrt{y^2-a}$, so any $y$ for which this expression is defined will do (square root is non-negative). So if we restrict ourselves to $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, and where the square root is non-negative, namely $y^2\geq a$, we get surjectivity.

for $2xy=b$ is easier, once we solve for $x,y$ for the first component, We can now just consider $k=xy$ a fixed constant, and $2k=b$ is well-defined.

Taking into account on the domain restrictions to obtain injectivity, and surjectivity, we have the domain where we have a linear isomorphism/diffeomorphism.

Comment: I am not understanding how you prove $\nabla (f)$ is linear isomorphism. $\det \nabla(f)\neq 0$ in S. How does that relates to the inverse function theorem as I have stated above? Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: It can only be a linear isomorphism if the map is linear and bijective. Since the map fails injectivity, it can't be bijective, and hence not an isomorphism. I don't think the function is surjective, but I am working that out now, if you restrict the domain to $S$, and prove surjectivity there (since it is already injective), then you will have a linear isomorphism

Comment: Were you able to work that out? I think that difeomorphism does not happen with all the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the linear operator is not going to be invertible in $\mathbb{R}^2-S$. However this is weird once it seems to contradict the question statement. Thanks for your effort insofar!

Comment: I edited my answer!